# MDN confusing concept for top property

Tags: html, css

```css
.text {
  position: relative;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  }
```

```html
<a class="text">Hello</a>
```

[Top](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/top)

> So As per MDN [Top](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/top) link quote:**When position is set to relative, the top property specifies the distance the element's top edge is moved below its normal position.**

So as per above quote my understanding is element's top edge should be moved below its normal position by 50% so why isn't it happening . Browser is EDGE 11.3 .

Comment: I assume root is the parent element because that the default parent element so i coded like:<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-US">
  <head>
    <style>
:root {
height:-400px;
}

.text {
  position: relative;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  }
    </style>
  </head>
<a class="text">Hello</strong>
</html> ` but still element not moving down to 50%

Comment: You're close, but not quite there. I moved my comment to an answer so that I could give you a code snippet that works

Answer (score 6, accepted):

MDN links to [the specification](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-position/#propdef-top).

Look carefully at what a percentage length means in this context:

> The inset is a percentage relative to the containing block’s size in the corresponding axis (e.g. width for left or right, height for top and bottom). For sticky positioned boxes, the inset is instead relative to the relevant scrollport’s size. Negative values are allowed.

The height of the containing block is `auto` (the default) and when a percentage is calculated of `auto` you get `0`.

Comment: 'Containing block' meaning please elaborate..is it a parent element?if so what should I consider for the contaning block/parent element/

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Containing_block#identifying_the_containing_block

Comment: so I assume containing block is the document itself which is root but still my text is not moving down . code used is `<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-US">
  <head>
    <style>
:root {
height:400px;
}

.text {
  position: relative;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  }
    </style>
  </head>
<a class="text">Hello</a>
</html>`

Comment: try `html, body {  height: 100% }` to set the parent of the element to full height. btw, this is not the best method to center element vertically. but close enough

Answer (score 2):

50% of what? The answer is 50% of the parent element. But by default, the parent element is only tall enough to contain the things within it. If you set a height on the parent element to completely fill the vertical height of the page, you will see that this element moves down to 50% of that, like this:

```css
html, body {
    height: 100%;
}

.text {
  position: relative;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  }
```

```html
<a class="text">Hello</strong>
```

Or a fixed height, like this:

```css
html, body {
    height: 200px;
}

.text {
  position: relative;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  }
```

```html
<a class="text">Hello</a>
```

Comment: works but as per https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:root that also says `The :root CSS pseudo-class matches the root element of a tree representing the document. In HTML, :root represents the <html> element and is identical to the selector html, except that its specificity is higher.` so why cant we use :root instead ?

Comment: @samreray because that doesn't include the `body` element. Even if you have not explicitly included this element in your code, the browser implicitly includes it.