# why parent child relationship is not maintained between <body> and <nav>

Tags: html, css

```css
nav {
  height: 10em;
}

.some_text {
  top: 50%;
  left: 40%;
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <a class="some_text">ABC</a>
</nav>
```

`body` css tag has no property defined,so shouldn't `nav` (being the child element of `body` also default to undeterministic properties meaning values which browser cannot use), and as a consequence **not** effect `<a>` placement in the browser?

refer:

- [for reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76249090/mdn-confusing-concept-for-top-property)
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Containing_block#identifying_the_containing_block
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/Building_blocks/Values_and_units#percentages

Comment: Waht do you mean whit _0/null properties_? For example user agent set nav as display:block;

Comment: i mean  undeterministic properties something whichthe browser cannot use.

Comment: your some_text is positioned top 50% relative to the nav height wich is set as 50em

Comment: What is _undeterministic properties_?

Comment: @Sfili_81  values which browser cant use

Comment: @quentin https://stackoverflow.com/q/76307646/21932665

Comment: @david if you can conceptually advise for my question

Comment: I don't understand the problem the MDN link you give says `...identifying the containing block depends [on] the element's position property: ... If the position property is ... relative ... the containing block is formed by the edge of the content box ... (such as ... block, ...` and `nav` is a `block` element. And later it is say `As noted above, when certain properties are given a percentage value, the computed value depends on the element's containing block.` so `nav` has the height `10em`, so `a` is moved by `50%` of the calculated value of `10em`. How das this contradict your observation?

Comment: adding new link if this helps:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76249090/mdn-confusing-concept-for-top-property

Comment: How do you think that link should be relevant for your question? The relevant container (ancestor) for the `a` element is the `nav` element because it has `display: block`?  And that one has a height given by `height: 10em;` so the `50%` is based on the height of that `nav` element. Why do you think that the `nav` element should not be the element to be considered by `a` but the `body`?

Comment: The `nav` has `display: block` by default (from the standard browser styles), which causes it to take the full width of the viewport. You have set `height: 10em` on the `nav`. Thus, the `a` then uses 40% of the viewport width as its left and 50% of `10em` as its top.

Comment: I put this question as I feel there should be a propagation effect from `body` to `nav` to `<a>` which is not happening.Reason:  as per https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76249090/mdn-confusing-concept-for-top-property `body` height will be set to 0 .next since `nav` is 10em of `body` so nav height value also becomes zero.next for `<a>`since .some_text is { top: 50%;} so `<a>` height also becomes zero.?

Comment: `10em` is not related to the (`body`) height but to the font size, so how is the `body` height relevant?

Comment: ok.. then how do we compute `nav` height value?

Comment: As I said based on the font size? If you write some text within `nav` that text is visible and has a size? As no styling is given in your css it is the default the browser uses for the `nav`. It is not clear to me why you think it can’t be calculated?

Comment: thats because i am assuming `body` height gonna be zero so `nav` height will be zero and `<a>` height will be zero also .thats my confusion

Comment: Again `em` is calculated based on `font-size` not on `height` (So for `em` the body height is completely irrelevant). And the `font-size` is **not** zero otherwise you would not see any text if you add it to the `nav` element? So if there is a `font-size` give why should `10em` result in a height of zero?

Comment: Try spotting difference in 2 ways.... 1st by removing `height:10em` value and observe in browser. 2nd keep `height:10em` value and observe in browser .

Comment: And what is the problem if you remove `height:10em`? It then behaves like described in the link you provided to the other question because `nav` has a height of `auto`? If add `height:10em` the height is calculated based on the `font-size` so it is not `auto` but defined. In both cases it exactly behaves like described on the MDN page.

Comment: if i remove `height:10em` text(ABC) is displayed on top of page ,whereas if I keep `height:10em` text(ABC) moves down , so as `em` is font-size related so shouldnt CSS ignore and show the text(ABC) in top of browser, in both cases(keeping 10 em or removing 10em)?

Comment: `em` is **calculated** based on the `font-size`, but you can apply it to any property that uses a size.
`top: 50%` is calculated based on the height of the containing block (`nav`), if no `height` is applied to `nav`, then `height` is `auto` and `50%` results in `0`. If `height` is `10em`, that height is calculated based on the `font-size` that is applied to `nav`. If the computed value of `font-size` e.g. is `10px` for `nav` then `height: 10em` results in `nav` being `10 [em]* 10px` = `100px` height,  so `top: 50%` will result in a computed value of `top: 50px` (50% of that 100px).

Comment: So as you say .... If the computed value of font-size e.g. is 10px for nav then where is that 10px value compute from or inputted from?

Comment: I give up. I already said that in the previous comments.

Comment: And even if not,  then asking why the default font size in browsers is larger then zero is a new question.

Comment: Something does happen in the background without any CSS: The CSS `:root/html` default font size is defined in the browser font settings. Varying per vendor this value can be set in pixels (e.g. Firefox) or a keyword (Chrome/Edge). When not changed by the user, the default value is `16px`. As `body` inherits from `html` it is also `16px`. Elements inside `body` inherit font size from `body`, making them also `16px`. So `nav { height: 10em }` makes the element `160px` tall as `1em = 16px` (where **em** means *inherit from nearest ancestor* being `body`). One of the 'cascading' effects of CSS.

Comment: Simply go to your browser settings and change the default font size to `32px`. You will see when you open/refresh your page the `<nav>` element will have become `320px` tall as `1em` is now `32px`. Therefore, the `ABC` text will be twice as big. Just something to remember, it will stick eventually. When you want to use `:root/html` font size use **rem** (default defined in font settings or overridden in CSS), if you want to use *nearest ancestor* font size use **em** (cascaded inheritance in CSS).

Comment: it seems you are not ready to accept any answer so why setting a bounty? The answer to your question is within the comments that you are not trying to understand

Comment: `body`'s height is `auto` and therefore based on its children. Its only child is the `nav`, which has a height of `10em`, which is based on the font size. The position of the `a` is then relative to this, based on the percentage offsets you specified.

Comment: What don't you understand of that?

Comment: "shouldn't nav (being the child element of body also default to undeterministic properties meaning values which browser cannot use)," — I don't understand why the *defaults* applied to the nav element are remotely relevant here since the nav element has a non-default height specified in the CSS.

Comment: @quentin can you rephrase..as I didnt get your point

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Problem

Some browsers add some CSS to the `<body>` HTML tag by default (see the ["Default CSS Settings"](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_body.asp) section at the bottom of the page). In fact, many other HTML tags also have some CSS set by default ([source](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_default_values.php)), generally speaking. All this depends on the browser you use. For the sake of simplicity, let's say you use a browser that does add some CSS to the `<body>` HTML tag by default (e.g., Chrome).

### Solution 1: Custom CSS

You can add the following CSS:

```
body {
  margin: 0;
}
```

If you don't add `body { margin: 0; }` CSS, the `<body>` tag will have `margin: 8px;` CSS set by default.

*Note: You can also find this CSS line in `normalize.css` ([source](https://necolas.github.io/normalize.css/8.0.1/normalize.css)). See Solution 2.*

[image: Screenshot 1]

### Solution 2: normalize.css

You can use [`normalize.css`](https://github.com/necolas/normalize.css/) to *make browsers render all elements more consistently and in line with modern standards*, as stated [here](https://necolas.github.io/normalize.css/).

```css
/*! normalize.css v8.0.1 | MIT License | github.com/necolas/normalize.css */

/* Document
   ========================================================================== */

/**
 * 1. Correct the line height in all browsers.
 * 2. Prevent adjustments of font size after orientation changes in iOS.
 */

html {
  line-height: 1.15; /* 1 */
  -webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%; /* 2 */
}

/* Sections
   ========================================================================== */

/**
 * Remove the margin in all browsers.
 */

body {
  margin: 0;
}

/**
 * Render the `main` element consistently in IE.
 */

main {
  display: block;
}

/**
 * Correct the font size and margin on `h1` elements within `section` and
 * `article` contexts in Chrome, Firefox, and Safari.
 */

h1 {
  font-size: 2em;
  margin: 0.67em 0;
}

/* Grouping content
   ========================================================================== */

/**
 * 1. Add the correct box sizing in Firefox.
 * 2. Show the overflow in Edge and IE.
 */

hr {
  box-sizing: content-box; /* 1 */
  height: 0; /* 1 */
  overflow: visible; /* 2 */
}

/**
 * 1. Correct the inheritance and scaling of font size in all browsers.
 * 2. Correct the odd `em` font sizing in all browsers.
 */

pre {
  font-family: monospace, monospace; /* 1 */
  font-size: 1em; /* 2 */
}

/* Text-level semantics
   ========================================================================== */

/**
 * Remove the gray background on active links in IE 10.
 */

a {
  background-color: transparent;
}

/**
 * 1. Remove the bottom border in Chrome 57-
 * 2. Add the correct text decoration in Chrome, Edge, IE, Opera, and Safari.
 */

abbr[title] {
  border-bottom: none; /* 1 */
  text-decoration: underline; /* 2 */
  text-decoration: underline dotted; /* 2 */
}

/**
 * Add the correct font weight in Chrome, Edge, and Safari.
 */

b,
strong {
  font-weight: bolder;
}

/**
 * 1. Correct the inheritance and scaling of font size in all browsers.
 * 2. Correct the odd `em` font sizing in all browsers.
 */

code,
kbd,
samp {
  font-family: monospace, monospace; /* 1 */
  font-size: 1em; /* 2 */
}

/**
 * Add the correct font size in all browsers.
 */

small {
  font-size: 80%;
}

/**
 * Prevent `sub` and `sup` elements from affecting the line height in
 * all browsers.
 */

sub,
sup {
  font-size: 75%;
  line-height: 0;
  position: relative;
  vertical-align: baseline;
}

sub {
  bottom: -0.25em;
}

sup {
  top: -0.5em;
}

/* Embedded content
   ========================================================================== */

/**
 * Remove the border on images inside links in IE 10.
 */

img {
  border-style: none;
}

/* Forms
   ========================================================================== */

/**
 * 1. Change the font styles in all browsers.
 * 2. Remove the margin in Firefox and Safari.
 */

button,
input,
optgroup,
select,
textarea {
  font-family: inherit; /* 1 */
  font-size: 100%; /* 1 */
  line-height: 1.15; /* 1 */
  margin: 0; /* 2 */
}

/**
 * Show the overflow in IE.
 * 1. Show the overflow in Edge.
 */

button,
input { /* 1 */
  overflow: visible;
}

/**
 * Remove the inheritance of text transform in Edge, Firefox, and IE.
 * 1. Remove the inheritance of text transform in Firefox.
 */

button,
select { /* 1 */
  text-transform: none;
}

/**
 * Correct the inability to style clickable types in iOS and Safari.
 */

button,
[type="button"],
[type="reset"],
[type="submit"] {
  -webkit-appearance: button;
}

/**
 * Remove the inner border and padding in Firefox.
 */

button::-moz-focus-inner,
[type="button"]::-moz-focus-inner,
[type="reset"]::-moz-focus-inner,
[type="submit"]::-moz-focus-inner {
  border-style: none;
  padding: 0;
}

/**
 * Restore the focus styles unset by the previous rule.
 */

button:-moz-focusring,
[type="button"]:-moz-focusring,
[type="reset"]:-moz-focusring,
[type="submit"]:-moz-focusring {
  outline: 1px dotted ButtonText;
}

/**
 * Correct the padding in Firefox.
 */

fieldset {
  padding: 0.35em 0.75em 0.625em;
}

/**
 * 1. Correct the text wrapping in Edge and IE.
 * 2. Correct the color inheritance from `fieldset` elements in IE.
 * 3. Remove the padding so developers are not caught out when they zero out
 *    `fieldset` elements in all browsers.
 */

legend {
  box-sizing: border-box; /* 1 */
  color: inherit; /* 2 */
  display: table; /* 1 */
  max-width: 100%; /* 1 */
  padding: 0; /* 3 */
  white-space: normal; /* 1 */
}

/**
 * Add the correct vertical alignment in Chrome, Firefox, and Opera.
 */

progress {
  vertical-align: baseline;
}

/**
 * Remove the default vertical scrollbar in IE 10+.
 */

textarea {
  overflow: auto;
}

/**
 * 1. Add the correct box sizing in IE 10.
 * 2. Remove the padding in IE 10.
 */

[type="checkbox"],
[type="radio"] {
  box-sizing: border-box; /* 1 */
  padding: 0; /* 2 */
}

/**
 * Correct the cursor style of increment and decrement buttons in Chrome.
 */

[type="number"]::-webkit-inner-spin-button,
[type="number"]::-webkit-outer-spin-button {
  height: auto;
}

/**
 * 1. Correct the odd appearance in Chrome and Safari.
 * 2. Correct the outline style in Safari.
 */

[type="search"] {
  -webkit-appearance: textfield; /* 1 */
  outline-offset: -2px; /* 2 */
}

/**
 * Remove the inner padding in Chrome and Safari on macOS.
 */

[type="search"]::-webkit-search-decoration {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
}

/**
 * 1. Correct the inability to style clickable types in iOS and Safari.
 * 2. Change font properties to `inherit` in Safari.
 */

::-webkit-file-upload-button {
  -webkit-appearance: button; /* 1 */
  font: inherit; /* 2 */
}

/* Interactive
   ========================================================================== */

/*
 * Add the correct display in Edge, IE 10+, and Firefox.
 */

details {
  display: block;
}

/*
 * Add the correct display in all browsers.
 */

summary {
  display: list-item;
}

/* Misc
   ========================================================================== */

/**
 * Add the correct display in IE 10+.
 */

template {
  display: none;
}

/**
 * Add the correct display in IE 10.
 */

[hidden] {
  display: none;
}
```

### Solution 3: Using Bootstrap

You can use Bootstrap, which removes the `margin` from the `<body>` HTML tag by default.

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Bootstrap demo</title>
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-rbsA2VBKQhggwzxH7pPCaAqO46MgnOM80zW1RWuH61DGLwZJEdK2Kadq2F9CUG65" crossorigin="anonymous">
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Hello, world!</h1>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-kenU1KFdBIe4zVF0s0G1M5b4hcpxyD9F7jL+jjXkk+Q2h455rYXK/7HAuoJl+0I4" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

If you run the snippet above and use [Developer Tools](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Common_questions/Tools_and_setup/What_are_browser_developer_tools) (i.e., press the F12 key), you can see that Bootstrap removes the `margin` in the `_reboot.scss` file by default. You don't need to do anything.

[image: Screenshot 2]

### Note

I want to emphasize that there's a very common mistake people make when setting the following CSS:

```
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0; /* Unnecessary! */
}
```

**There's no need to set `padding: 0;` to the `<body>` HTML tag since it only has  `margin: 8px;` CSS set by default, but not `padding`!** Setting the following CSS is enough:

```
body {
  margin: 0;
}
```

Comment: Strange. How come this is accepted, yet the answer was rewritten previously to ask about how setting a height on the `nav` affects the placement of the `a`? What is the actual question?

Comment: *"the `<body>` tag will have `margin: 8px;` CSS set by default"* - 8px margin on any browser? that seems unlikely

Comment: @ITgoldman It depends on the browser. I edited my answer to emphasize this.

Comment: Like Darryl Noakes, I don't understand what this answer has to do with the question (which seems to be asking why the nav element has a non-zero height).

Answer (score 1):

The implicit `body` tag has default css which might change between browsers. For example the `padding`.

```css
nav {
  height: 10em;
  background: blue;
}

.some_text {
  top: 50%;
  left: 40%;
  position: relative;
  background: red;
}

body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  border: 1px solid gray;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <a class="some_text">ABC</a>
</nav>
```

Comment: i didnt understand your comment,quote:*which might change between browsers. For example the padding.*

Comment: each browser has its own default values for non styled elements. this is why we use scripts like 'normalize.css' or 'reset.css' or any other framework, so that the html would look the same on "any" browser

Answer (score 0):

It's because you have given a height of `50em` to your `nav` element. Try removing that.

Comment: please re read question

Answer (score -1):

At present, at least two **reasons** can be foreseeable:

1. block height is too high (CSS → `height: 50em`);
2. The text is positioned from the middle of the block horizontally (CSS → `top: 50%`).

**Solutions**/Hints:

1. Try decreasing one of those values (or both).
2. Try to add to the CSS code `border: 1px solid #0ff;` under the line `height: 50em;` for clarity.

Comment: not addressing question

Comment: @tennis, your **question** title (and therefore meaning) **was** totally **changed** to another. You previous version of question was something like: "Why does the text slide down?".